# Cómo usar variables dentro de sed

Tags: linux, bash, variables, shell, sed

Quiero usar variables `$nombre` y `$x` dentro de sed (dentro de un ciclo)

```
for x in {1..797}
nombre=`awk -v x="$x" 'NR==x fichero 1`
sed -i '/$nombre/c $x' fichero
```

*los nombres pueden ser una, dos o tres palabras separadas por espacios y otras veces una palabra y un número de 1 o 2 dígitos (y en un caso tiene paréntesis)*

Logré que el sed considere la x como variable e hiciese el reemplazo usando `sed 's/nombre/'${x}'/' fichero` o también en el caso de  `sed "/nombre/c $x" fichero`
pero al intentar definir lo que quiero sustituir a través de una variable no lo consigo.
Imagino que es algo relacionado al uso de las comillas simples y dobles pero he probado lo que le sirvió a otros y no me funciona.

Obtuve estos errores y simplemente ninguna sustitución

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: undetermined addres regex
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: undetermined `s' command
```

Comment: creo que debiese haber un slash entre $x y la comilla de cierre

Answer (score 1):

Para usar una variable en sed debes utilizar comillas dobles para que así se interprete su contenido:

```sh
sed "s/..../$variable/"
#   ^                 ^
```

Ejemplo:

```sh
$ bla="adios"
$ echo "hola" | sed 's/hola/$bla/'  # <-- con comilla simple
$bla
$ echo "hola" | sed "s/hola/$bla/"  # <-- con comilla doble
adios
```

Comment: Entiendo tu ejemplo y al probar usando echo, funciona. Sin embargo al aplicarlo a mi códido donde hay 2 VARIABLES en el comando: sed "s/$nombre/$x/" no hace nada. Vale decir que ya probé que $nombre y $x estuvieran bien ingresadas. Pienso que el problema puede ser que hay más de una variables

Comment: @GabrielleCórdovaVelásquez prueba esto: `nombre="hola"; x="sustituto"; echo "hola" | sed "/^$nombre$/c $x"`. En cualquier caso, ¿cuál es el problema que intentas solucionar? Al código en tu pregunta le falta cerrar `'` en awk. Si explicas el problema más general con el que te enfrentas, tal vez pueda ayudarte más por allí. También podría mirarse si hay valores _raros_ en el fichero o en las variables.