# Cómo podría insertar variables en las expresiones regulares?

Tags: linux, regex, bash, sed

Estoy necesitando hacer la sustitución de la expresión regular `tdini_lineal_0045_S2` por `tdini_lineal_var1_var2` usando *sed*, y la voy a hacer varias veces.

Ll problema es que cada vez *var1* y *var2* van a tomar valores distintos, es decir, debo ponerlos como variables dentro de la expresión regular. podrían ayudarme?

```
sed -i 's/tdini_lineal_0045_S2/tdini_lineal_var1_var2/g' archivo
```

gracias!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Alguien ya respondió una pregunta similar en esta publicación de este sitio:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/444720/cómo-usar-variables-dentro-de-sed
La respuesta corta es usar comillas dobles y la notación de variable de bash `"tdini_lineal_$var1_$var2"`

Comment: @Cuauhtli es duplicada de esa, efectivamente. La pena es que la otra no tiene ninguna respuesta con reputación superior a 0, por lo que no deja sugerir el duplicado.

Comment: Algún día me dedicaré exclusivamente a puntuar respuestas

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Cómo usar variables dentro de sed](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/444720/c%c3%b3mo-usar-variables-dentro-de-sed)

Answer (score 1):

Seria algo asi

```
var2=S3
var1=0046
echo 'tdini_lineal_0045_S2' | sed "s/tdini_lineal_0045_S2/tdini_lineal_${var1}_${var2}/g"
```

resultando en

```
tdini_lineal_0046_S3
```

es importante delimitar las variables con `{}` porque `_` es un caracter valido para un nombre de variable.